# How to delay Rmarkdown chunk execution to run only after Shiny components have loaded

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, shiny-server

I have an RMarkdown document that is written similarly to this one below.
It has a Shiny app embedded into it which ultimately saves a dataframe to the global environment so that later chunks in the document can then use it.

The problem is, I am running into an error where the final chunk cannot locate the dataframe produced by the Shiny  app. I suspect that this is because the Shiny app has not finished loading yet, before the final chunk is run. Is there a way to delay the execution of the final code chunk so that it only runs after the Shiny app loads?

The Shiny app is a non negotiable as (the real thing) contains js scripts that authenticate and ensure secure access to the company database.

There might be another reason why the dataframe is inaccessible - if anyone has any ideas, please let me know! Thanks

```
---
  title: test_markdown
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
  orientation: rows
vertical_layout: scroll
runtime: shiny
---
```

```
{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(shiny)

# serve the files
addResourcePath(prefix = 'files', directoryPath = 'www')
```

```
{r global, include=FALSE}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache =TRUE)


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
  tags$script(src = "https://alcdn.msauth.net/browser/2.35.0/js/msal-browser.js")),
  # tags$script(src = "files/customJSscript")
)


server <- function(input, output){
  
  data <- reactive({
    "EXAMPLE OBJECT"
  })
  
  observeEvent(data(),{
    assign("A", data(), envir = .GlobalEnv)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

```
{r}

print(A)
```